# export function with promise in nodejs

Tags: node.js, function, import, promise

I am trying to import a function from an external file I have, which contains a promise.
The resolution of the promise is what should be returned, but I get an error message:
The requested module './functions.js' does not provide an export named 'getOkapiToken'
The POST request works fine when I run it directly in the server, but I need it in a separate file as it will be used by several different files in the future.
This is also the first time I'm using promises, so I'm not sure I handled it properly (though I can't get any errors registered until I deal with the first one).

The functions.js file is built as follows:

```
import post from 'axios';

export function getOkapiToken(url, user, password) {
    //Get username and password for API
    const auth = {
      "username": user,
      "password": password
    };

    //Create headers for POST request
    const options = {
      method: 'post',
      data: auth,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': auth.length,
        'X-Okapi-Tenant': 'diku'
      }
    };
      //Make API post call
    post(url+':9130/authn/login', options)
        .then(response => {
          return(response.headers['x-okapi-token'])
        }).catch((err) => {
            return(`There was an error 2: ${err}`)
    })
  }
```

And I try to import it as follows:

```
import { getOkapiToken } from './functions3.js'
import settings from './jsons/config.json';
let OkapiKey = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  //Call function to make API post call  
  let keytoken = getOkapiToken(settings.url,settings.userauth,settings.passauth)
  console.log(`There was an error: ${keytoken}`)
  if (keytoken.length == 201) {
    resolve(keytoken)
  } else {
    reject('There was an error')
  }
})

OkapiKey.then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error('I have an error:'+err.code);
})
```

Comment: Change `module.export` to `export ...`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: @Marc Thanks! I had to change the entire export to an "export function" syntax, but that seems to have worked! The result is still undefined, but at least now I get a response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to handle asynchronous task in Javascript and wit Node.JS

1. Pass in a **Callback** to run in the asynchronous code
2. Use a **Promise** that will either resolve or reject the promise
3. Use the **async** keyword in front of the function and place **await** in front of the asynchronous code.

With that said I was able to get the code to work by running a [simple node server](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/) and I modified your code just a bit to get a response back from the server.

index.js

```
const  { getOkapiToken } = require('./functions.js')
const settings = require('./settings.json')
var OkapiKey = getOkapiToken(settings.url,settings.userauth,settings.passauth)
OkapiKey
.then((data) => {
  console.log('I have data'+ data.toString())
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error('I have an error:'+err.code);
})
```

functions.js

```
const post  = require('axios');

const getOkapiToken = (url, user, password) =>
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

      //Get username and password for API
      const auth = {
        "username": user,
        "password": password
      };

      //Create headers for POST request
      const options = {
        method: 'post',
        data: auth,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': auth.length,
          'X-Okapi-Tenant': 'diku'
        }
      };

      post('http://localhost:3000/', options)
          .then(response => {
            resolve(response.data)
            // if (response.headers['x-okapi-token']) {
            //   resolve(response.headers['x-okapi-token']);
            // } else {
            //   reject((error));
            // }
          }).catch((err) => {
            console.error('Response Error:'+err)
      })
    })

exports.getOkapiToken = getOkapiToken;
```

Comment: Hi @meddy! Thanks for that!
Is there a way to keep the function.js with just a function, then call the promise in the index.js file? I tried to do that, but got an error message: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'axios' imported from C:\xampp\htdocs\NodeAPI\functions.js

Comment: p.s. I'm also getting that error message when I try to run the code you wrote: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'axios' imported from C:\xampp\htdocs\NodeAPI\functions.js

Comment: Axios is the asynchronous code that the promise is to resolve or reject. If you move axios to the index.js file then yes. As far as second reply mkae sure you have the axios package installed.

Comment: I managed to get a correct response with the way you did it.
I then tried to build on that to get the promise out of the function file, but the response I get when I make the call to the function is "undefined" (I don't even get the error message I inserted at the catch). I updated the original post with the new code I built, but I can't find the problem. Since I use OkapiKey.then I don't need to use "await" right?

Comment: In order to use await you have to use an async function. Your IDE should throw an error or warning indicating that the syntax is invaild. Here are a few example I mocked up to help you understand async and await. [See Example](https://repl.it/@MatthewEddy/nodejs-playground-1#index.js)