# How to export promise variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, export, commonjs

what I am trying to do is to export set_cookies and csrf_token from the GetSolManCredentials.js to Create.js.
I have tried to export the values as variables: `module.exports.csrf_token  =csrf_token;`
or even as function by creating a function `module.exports = function (){}`.
However, no luck.

**GetSolManCredentials.js**

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

   request.onload = () => {
      console.log(request.status);
      if (request.status == 200) {
        var cookies = request.getResponseHeader("set-cookie");
        var set_cookies = cookies[2];
        console.log("Cookies: " + set_cookies);
        var csrf_token = request.getResponseHeader("x-csrf-token");
        console.log("csrf token: " + csrf_token);
        resolve(set_cookies,csrf_token);
      } else {
        reject ("Something went wrong while getting cookies");
      }
    }
  });
```

**Create.js**

```
var returnToken = require("./GetSolManCredentials.js");
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [export function with promise in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64766214/export-function-with-promise-in-nodejs)

Comment: I've tried exporting it as function. However, when I require it returns an error indicating its not a function